# Maximum stress point

Tags: stresses

[image]

I want to determine the point where the maximum stress is located. Also, I want to know how this kind of questions is answered.

Answer (score 1):

let's say the coefficient of bounding between the plastic rod and concrete is q and the diameter of the plastic rod is d, meaning every square inch of the plastic embedded in the concrete has q lbs adhesion, thus $q\pi d $ for every inch length of embedment.

Therefore the bound between the plastic rod and concrete starts from zero at point A and linearly increases to the level where the bound becomes equal to maximum tension the plastic rod can take. Assuming the maximum tensile strength of the plastic rod $ F_p $ this point is located at an embedment length of:

$L_{embement}=\frac{F_p*Area\ of\ rod}{q\pi d}= \frac{F_p\pi d^2/4}{q\pi d}=\frac{F_pd}{4q}$

This point is independent of the points B, C, D on the graph. It is pre-determined by the properties of the plastic rod. but it certainly is not at point A, because there the concrete stress is zero.

I attach a graph of concrete bounding stress here. The stress in rod depends on its embedment length.

The axial tensile stress in the rod at point A is the sum of cylindrical shear stress plus the cone shear stress.

.
**EDIT**

I added the narrowing of the rod under the Poisson's effect to clarify why shear stress at point A is zero. Notice that due to axial elongation under tension the rod gets a bit narrower through a transition region from the Point A inward.

.

[image: diagram of bounding stress]

Comment: Your diagram does not show a concrete stress of zero at A. The axial tension stress is zero, but the adhesion shear stress is not.

Comment: @ingenørd, the axial tensile stress in the rod at point A is the sum of cylindrical shear stress plus the cone shear stress. I guess I should add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is A. It's mainly because of the elastic modulus of those materials. The plastic is very flexible and can't transfer the force to the end of the hole. So the force is transfered at the outer end. If the materials would be interchanged, the maximum stress would be located at the end of the hole.

Comment: The stress at A is not zero using your assumptions, because there is a shear force acting on the inside of the hole. But I agree that unless you make some assumptions which the OP doesn't mention, the answer could be anything. Actually, I would go for D, because for a perfectly sharp reentrant corner the stress around the *edge* of the end of the hole would theoretically be infinite.

Comment: @alephzero, I drew a diagram of concrete shear stress showing concrete stress at A is zero. The OP doesn't need to give much more info. He asks for a typical method of handling the embedment of a bar in concrete. This is the typical method engineering codes handle it.

Comment: @kamran, The shear stress at point A can't be zero. The elastic properties of both materials has to be taken into account to sovle this.

Comment: @teshim, the plastic rod under the tension will strain and elongate. At the same time, it will narrow down by Poisson's, v ratio. so during a transition length starting at A into concrete, there is a gradient of shear from zero to fully stressed shown by the cone.

Comment: @kamran I agree on the first part but the maximum is at point A and the shear stress will decrease further inwards. You can easily see this by FE model.

Comment: Maximum tensile stress in the rod is at A of course because it's the sum of all shear along the embedment. But shear stress  on concrete is not. Unless you consider the necking of the rod and microscopic cracks and bulging of concrete at the entry point you don't have a realistic model.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. Now. I understand that the maximum stress in concrete will start to increase linearly after point A until it reaches the maximum. But, we cannot determine exactly at which point?